# How to create stack in tutum with docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker-compose, tutum

I am trying to build a Stack as follows:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - '6379'
app:
  build: .
  links:
    - redis
```

when I push "Create Stack" button, I get this error:

```
Oops!

Service 'app': Value {u'build': u'.', u'links': [u'redis'], u'name': u'app'} for field '<obj>' contains additional property 'build' not defined by 'properties' or 'patternProperties' and additionalProperties is False. See 'https://support.tutum.co/support/solutions/articles/5000583471' for more details
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Tutum documentation](https://support.tutum.co/support/solutions/articles/5000583471-stack-yaml-reference) states the following at the bottom of the page:

> ## Docker-compose non-supported keys
>
> Tutum.yml has been designed with docker-compose.yml in mind to maximize compatibility, but the following keys are not supported:
>
> ```
> build
> external_links
> env_file
> ```

This clearly states that `build` is not a supported key, which is what your error message also says. It looks like you'll have to remove the `build` key from your file.